# How to create phase plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate spectrum of the signal and plot its magnitude and phase in matlab.
I have figured out how to do the magnitude plot, but cant understand how to do a phase plot

```
N = 1000; Ts = 0.05; Fs = 1/Ts;
t = [0:Ts:(N*Ts)-Ts];

xc = 4*exp(1i*5*pi*t) + 6*exp(1i*12*pi*t);
f=[-Fs/2:Fs/N:Fs/2-Fs/N];

Xc=fft(xc);

figure;

subplot(211)

plot(f,fftshift(abs(Xc))) ;title('Magnitude as a function of Hz');

xlabel('f in Hz');ylabel('|Xc|');grid on;

subplot(212)

w=2*pi*f;

plot(w,fftshift(abs(Xc))) ;title('Magnitude as a function of w');

xlabel('w');ylabel('|Xc|');grid on;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `abs` you use for a magnitude plot with `angle`, like:

```matlab
plot(w,fftshift(angle(Xc))) ;title('Phase as a function of w');
```